# How to log into Azure using personal account

Tags: azure

I have an Azure account which I log into using a personal MS account.

The account email address is also an address in office365 for business. Therefore the same email address is also classed as a work account.

Usually when I log into Azure, you can specify if you want to use the personal or business account. Since today that functionality seems to have been removed and it always overrides with the work account.

Therefore when I log into azure it takes me to a completely separate azure account which is associated with a work account instead of the personal account.

Anybody know how to log into the Azure portal using a personal account only?

Comment: When you see the portal: Did you click in the upper-right where your name is, to see the list of available directories you're signed into? Since you use the same email address for multiple subscriptions, maybe a different one is showing up as the default now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your browser cache and cookies.

Once cleared the option to choose Personal or Work account will appear again when you enter your email address.

A good way around this is to use two different browsers, one for Azure Personal account and a different one for Azure Work account. That way you dont have to keep clearing your cookies.

Comment: I have the same issue with a client's email account.  I am unable to get the login prompt to give us the option for personal login, instead of defaulting to work/school.

I even used an incognito window.